# Coding a recurrence relation in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I am writing a code that calculates a recursive mathematical problem, called foo.

The condition should be,
if `n < 4`: `foo(n) = n`
if `n >= 4`: `foo(n) = n + foo(n - 1) + 2*foo(n-2)`.

```
public class foo {

    public static int foo(n) {
        if(n < 4) {
            return n;
        } else if(n >= 4) {

        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }   
}
```

I am stuck here...
My final purpose is to state the values of  foo(1), foo(2), foo(3), foo(4), foo(5), foo(6), foo(7).

Also, am I allowed to put the main method in that foo class?

Comment: Just put the stated logic in your else statement - `return n + foo(n - 1) + 2*foo(n-2);`

Comment: You do not need the `if` in the `else` case... Or maybe you should add a check beforehand....

Comment: Also you don't need to check if `n >= 4`. Just the `else` is enough.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780246/recursive-function-in-java/45780295) for more details on this.

Comment: You can even do this using a one-line *ternary* statement: `return (n < 4) ? n : n + foo(n - 1) + 2 * foo(n - 2);`

Answer (score 2):

The following function is the one you're looking for:

```
public static int bar(int n){
    if(n < 4){
        return n;
    } 
    return n + bar(n - 1) + 2*bar(n-2);
}
```

First of all, if you just want a function which you will call from `main` directly, it must be `static`, because you're not allowed to call non-static method from the static context.

`static` functions (methods) are called on classes, not on objects. Therefor, there is no need to create an object - just execute `Foo.bar(anyInt)`.

Then, you need to check if n is smaller than 4 - if it is, `return n`.

There is no need for an `else` clause, because if we returned inside if, we won't execute any more code from that function, as `return` means also `exit this function now`.

Then, please follow Java naming strategies, so start class name with capital letter (`Foo` instead of `foo`). `foo` is perfect name for a field, variable or a method, but not for a class.

The code should in the end look like:

```
public class Foo {

    public static int bar(int n){
        if(n < 4){
            return n;
        } 
        return n + bar(n - 1) + 2*bar(n-2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
            System.out.println("bar(" + i + ") is " + Foo.bar(i));
        }
    }   
}
```

The output will be:

```
>bar(1) is 1
>bar(2) is 2
>bar(3) is 3
>bar(4) is 11
>bar(5) is 22
>bar(6) is 50
>bar(7) is 101
```

Comment: Not mine. Your code works, so I'd definitely upvote (+1).

Answer (score 1):

The following method will work as well.

```
public static int foo(int n) {
      return n < 4 ? n : (n + foo(n-1) + (2*foo(n-2)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] main) {
    // a loop runs to get value of foo(1)...foo(7)
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
         // the returned value is printed over here
        System.out.println(foo(i));
    }
}

public static int foo(int n) {
    // this goes according to your formulae
    if (n < 4) {
        return n;
    }
    else {
        // by using recursion we are evaluating the value
        // here foo(n-1) and foo(n-2) provides the required
        // values which is being added to 'n' and being returned 
        return (n + foo(n - 1) + 2 * foo(n - 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some plain English explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Do this and it should work:

```
public class foo {

    public static int mfoo(n)
    {
        if(n < 4) return n;            //no need for else if
        else return n + foo(n - 1) + 2*foo(n-2);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = 10; //number to calculate for
        System.out.println(foo(n));

    }   
}
```

You can keep the main method in the `foo` class if you want to execute it directly. If you want to execute it from another class, make the `main()` funtion in that class and call this one like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
    foo newFoo =  new foo();
    System.out.println(newFoo.mfoo(10));
```

NOTE: **DO NOT** name your method as the class name (foo). **Only** Constructors can do that and this is **NOT** a constructor.